# ivar for view controller in appdelegate.m

Tags: ios, initialization, storyboard

**edit 1**

I am adding some code to indicate its state after I have tried to work with `codeInOrange`'s answer so far which so far behaves like my code originally behaved, that is sample link shows up at first in the text field and can be altered by the user, but when the user returns to the VC, any new link text has been replaced by the original sample link. My reason for posting this additional code is to try to reconnect with `codeInOrange`'s promising answer because I am misunderstanding the logical flow of his original suggestions and his later comments.

In the current Storyboard I  am leaving the Text field and the Placeholder Text empty because the sample link seems to be adequately supplied by the `viewDidLoad` method below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.urlNameInput.text = @"sample http";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.urlNameInput.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    self.urlNameInput.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;   
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == self.urlNameInput) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self processPbn];
    }
    return YES;
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    // self.urlNameInput.text = appDelegate.stringForTextField;
    appDelegate.stringForTextField = self.urlNameInput.text;
}

- (void) processPbn
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlNameInput.text] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *connection, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         // lots of detail code has been elided in this method 
         self.iboard = 0;
         NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression  regularExpressionWithPattern:toMatch options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:&error];
         for (NSTextCheckingResult* board in [regex matchesInString:string options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])])
         {

         if (self.iboard>0) {
             AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

             appDelegate.stringForTextField = self.urlNameInput.text;
         }
     }];
}
```

**edit 1**

**edit 0**

I do not want to preserve the text between application shutdowns and launches, so the answer using `NSUserDefaults` is not quite what I need.

Also, it appears from my trials that the solution suggested by Michael Dautermann which suggests either putting my intialization text in `viewDidLoad` or in the Xib or Storyboard, does not work because the text always returns to its initial value upon return to the VC (likely because the `viewDidLoad` method is triggered), so I think I do **need to create an ivar in my AppDelegate.m** as I asked in my original question, and not in my ViewController.m `viewDidLoad`, **to get the desired result**, apparently. Perhaps it would be easier to create a B00L ivar in AppDelegate.m which is a flag that tells whether original text or current text is desired. But I cannot figure out how to do that, either. So, please consider this edit in your answer.

**edit 0**

My AppDelegate.m contains the following code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        BDViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.viewController = (id)vc;
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In the VC I want an ivar, an NSString, to be set at launch so that it can be the example text in my UITextField. Later I want that UITextField to be adjusted to an new value when the user supplies valid text into a UITextField.

Currently in my VC.h, the text field is declared and is synthesized in VC.m as follows .

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  UITextField *urlNameInput;


@synthesize urlNameInput;
```

I have tried putting the following code into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but do not see the desired text when I run the app.

```
    self.viewController.urlNameInput.text = @"example http";
```

How can I programmatically accomplish my goal of initializing the UITextField?

Comment: In your storyboard you can set the initial text for the textfield which remains until the value is changed. Is there a reason you aren't using that? Also are you trying to make the new text the user inputs remain for the duration of their session?

Comment: Yes, I am setting the original text in the Storyboard so the user can use the text as his/her first example of a valid web link. And it works up to a point in that that first example will produce its desired result, and a new valid link will produce its (different) desired result. But if the user moves on to the next VC and returns to review the link, s/he always sees the example link, not the incumbent link, as I wish. Yes I want the user input to remain for the duration of their session.

Comment: ok so basically you want the example http to be there when they first see it, but once they enter something in the text field that new value should remain until it is changed again?

Comment: Correct. I don't think I can use just the normal "Prompt" message, because it disappears when the user taps the textfield to enter new text. Maybe there is a way -- which I have not found -- to keep the "Prompt" message until the user erases or edits it?

Comment: I think you are setting the placeholder text instead of the actual text in storyboard...If you click on your textfield in storyboard is the sample text directly under 'plain' or 'attributed' or is it under the text color dropdown (in the attributes inspector)

Comment: No, I am selecting the actual text in storyboard. Above when I said "Prompt" I should have said "Placeholder", which does not seem to work for my wishes, unless you can tell me a way to adapt the "Placeholder" text to my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I think I understand now. The placeholder text is behaving as usual, and you can't have both placeholder text as well as a normal text entry. If you are comfortable using the textFieldDelegate protocol, you can intervene when a user didBeginEditing on the text field, and use the placeholder value as the actual text value. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense but I am not familiar with the textFieldDelegate protocol or with didBeginEditing. It sounds like a good approach but more than I can manage right now. Your answer below, building on codeInOrange's, has too many options that I am not familiar with, too. Thanks a lot for your comments. I had no idea I was trying to do something so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Put that "`urlNameInput.text =`" bit into your view controller's "`viewDidLoad`" method, instead of the "`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`" method (where your view controller is not likely yet instantiated.

Even better than that, just set the initial text in your storyboard or XIB file and then you can programmatically adjust it later on.

Comment: My app currently does initialize the text in the Storyboard and updates it programmatically, but when the user goes on to the next VC (which receives the text via a `prepareForSegue:`) and then returns to the initial VC after the text was changed by the user, the text reverts to the Storyboard initialized text. So I was looking for the approach mentioned in my question. But maybe the problem is elsewhere. Is the problem here? `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == self.urlNameInput) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}`

Comment: Am I mixing up using `self.urlNameInput` and `urlNameInput`? I am exclusively using `self.urlNameInput` (except in setting the following 2 properties of the textfield `urlNameInput.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    urlNameInput.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;`), but whenever I leave the main VC and then return back to it, the textfield contains the default text, not the changed text. I am guessing this behavior is due to the return triggering the `viewDidLoad` method. That is why my original question was trying to use the AppDelegate to initialize the textfield  What am I missing?

Comment: "`urlNameInput`" is a property, so you always need to tell the compiler which object *owns* this property.  If you are setting properties, you should do something like "`self.urlNameInput.clearButtonMode = ...`" if you are doing that within your view controller or "`self.viewController.urlNameInput.clearButtonMode = ...`" if you are doing that from your AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks. Ok. I changed those property settings to prefix each with `self.`, but I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do but creating an NSString iVar on your app delegate (although there are many other solutions) will allow you to set the textfield text to whatever you want when that VC comes back on the screen.

In your `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringForTextField;
```

This way you can initialize your textfield text when the view is loaded (viewDidLoad)

```
self.urlNameInput.text = @"example http";
```

then whenever that text value needs to be changed (say for example in `textFieldShouldReturn` in the other view controller. I'm assuming you have another textfield based on your question)

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

appDelegate.stringForTextField = textField.text;
```

and in viewDidAppear in the VC with the textField set that value.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

self.urlNameInput.text = appDelegate.stringForTextField;
```

probably not the best way to go about it, but it will work.

EDIT

Ok in viewDidAppear:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

if ([appDelegate.stringForTextField isEqualToString:@""]){

    self.urlNameInput.text = @"example http";

} else {

    self.urlNameInput.text = appDelegate.stringForTextField; 

}
```

Now what this will do is if the user goes to another view controller, and comes back, the text field text will be what the user last entered, unless in another view controller, stringForTextField is updated to some new value. If this still does not work, look at your processPbn method to make sure the if clause is entered and that value is set. Otherwise it will always say "example http"

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but ... Even though I have **also** left the `@"example http";` in the storyboard field, no text appears there on launch of the app. I wonder about `textField.text` in your answer in `textFieldShouldReturn`; is `textField.text` a typo, because I don't see it anywhere else?

Comment: textField is the textField parameter in that method, representing the textField that invoked that delegate method call

Comment: also from your property declaration it doesn't look like you connected you textfield via an IBOutlet so the storyboard might not know that self.urlNameInput is the textField in your storyboard

Comment: In my storyboard Connections inspector under Outlets `delegate` is associated with `View Controller` and under Referencing Outlets `urlNameInput` is associated with `View Controller` (not with `stringForTextField`). Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah thats correct. I have no idea without looking at your project why there would be no text there, thats wierd

Comment: `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == self.urlNameInput) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        
        appDelegate.stringForTextField = textField.text;
        [self processPbn];
    }
    return YES;
}` Is the problem here? I only added your suggestion to the existing code.

Comment: No thats correct, now in viewDidAppear when you go back, get that string value, `appDelegate.stringForTextField` and assign it `self.urlNameInput.text`

Comment: Well, I had it backwards. I had `self.urlNameInput.text = appDelegate.stringForTextField;`, instead of `appDelegate.stringForTextField = self.urlNameInput.text ;`, so now the initial example text appears as desired, **but** I still get that example text when I return to the VC. So it still is not working.

Comment: I don't think you understand the flow of my solution

Comment: In method `processPbn` (which I have not exposed yet) is where I want the textField to be updated in side an if clause. Should the code that you suggested for either `textFieldShouldReturn:` or for `viewDidAppear:` be placed instead in `processPbn`? Sorry I am so slow witted.

Comment: the code that sets the text for the urlNameInput can be put in viewDidAppear. So you could check if stringForTextField is nil and set it to the initial text for when the view first appears, then if you change the value of stringForTextField somewhere else when you go back to that view it will update the textField text

Comment: Please look at the new **edit 1** I have added to my question. Perhaps the additional code will enable you to understand what I am doing. Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I did not see your comment. When I tried your new `viewDidAppear:`, nothing at all appears in the initial textField. `NSLog(@"viewDidAppear: %@", appDelegate.stringForTextField);` at the beginning of `viewDidAppear:` produces `(null)`.

Comment: It should be null because you haven't set anything to it when it first calls that method and the user hasn't entered in any text to the text field, thats why it should set the value to "example http". If it entered that clause then there is something wrong with your UITextfield connection, because it should set the initial text.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with my UITextField connection because when I use the code in my **edit 1** section, I see the initial "sample http" just fine, but I see nothing with this most recent EDIT of yours.

Comment: OK there must be something else that I can't see because I'm not looking at your project, I'm really sorry. I know that what I've posted will work if everything is set up correctly

Comment: Please see the answer I have posted. It may be exactly your answer, but I swear I could not quite see how your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect usage for NSUserDefaults. When the user enters something just store it in NSUserDefaults. Check to see if the NSUserDefaults entry is blank on each launch, and if so just display the original string.

Save the text in NSUserDefaults with something like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"yourNewString" forKey:@"userTextEntered"];
```

And then just check it on each launch:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userTextEntered"])
{
    //display the user entered string
}
else
{
    //display the string that you want to display prior to text being entered
}
```

However, this solution is only necessary if you want to **preserve the text between application shutdowns and launches**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding why it's unimportant to persist the previous value across application launches, especially when it is beneficial to your users to have it persist only during the application lifecycle.  codeInOrange's answer works by adding a property to the AppDelegate. The only thing I would add to his answer is a conditional `if()` . If you want to do it without any properties, you can still use the NSUserDefaults.

At the top of your ViewController.m file

```
#define SetHTTPString(string) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:string forKey:@"HTTPString"] //no semicolon
#define GetHTTPString() [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"HTTPString"] //no semicolon
```

Then, in viewWillAppear...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSString *httpString = GetHTTPString();
    if (httpString) {
        self.urlNameInput.text = httpString;
    } else {
        self.urlNameInput.text = @"Example http";
    }
}
```

Next, in the method where the user enters text and "enters it"

```
...methodToEnterURL {
    SetHTTPString(self.urlNameInput.text);
}
```

Finally, if you absolutely want to destroy the value in the NSUserDefaults, add this method to your AppDelegate's didEnterBackground method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"Example http" forKey:@"HTTPString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes that the Storyboard contains the initial, default Text (of at least 3 characters length).

I really appreciated the help I got from others, especially from **codeInOrange** . I actually believe this is  codeInOrange's solution, but I was never able to quite put his pieces together until I finally stumbled upon this one.

I hope this is really a valid answer, and apologize to all if I did not state my question clearly or if I mistook others' valid answers, especially  codeInOrange.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  StickyPlaceholder
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize textInput;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if (!appDelegate.stringForTextField)appDelegate.stringForTextField = self.textInput.text ;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if (textField == self.textInput) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
// next line is dummy processing            
        if (self.textInput.text.length>2)appDelegate.stringForTextField = self.textInput.text;

    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.textInput.text = appDelegate.stringForTextField;
}

@end
```

[image: Storyboard]